# How to access Hadoop from another machine on same network?

Tags: hadoop, networking, ssh

I have one machine running Hadoop and I do want to access Ambari by another machine on the same network.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons, ports used by Hadoop cannot be accessed over a public IP address. To connect to Hadoop from a different machine, you must the open port of the service you want to access remotely. I believe Openstack provides the option for assigning Floating IPs. That's one of the options to enable you to access remotely. You must create a port redirect rule on your VM program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped. I've just changed the NetWork from NAT to Bridged and I'm able to connect thru 192.168...